# Django. Есть переменная в файле views.py - Post.objects.all()[:10]. Выдает 10 сообщений. Как перенести это форматирование [:10] в файл settings.py

Tags: python, django

Есть переменная в файле `views.py` - `Post.objects.all()[:10]`. Выдает 10 сообщений. Как перенести это форматирование `[:10]` в файл `settings.py`
В самом файле `views.py` попробовал разбить на несколько переменных - получилось так

```
def index(request):
    x = Post.objects.all()
    y = x[:3]
    posts = y
```

Вот теперь встал вопрос как сделать так чтоб эту часть перенести в settings.py

Comment: from django.conf import settings.

Comment: count_posts = settings.COUN_POSTS

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич правильно понимаю в setting переношу переменную "y" и присваиваю ей имя COUNT_POSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле `settings.py` создаете параметр конфигурации, т.е. переменную:

```
POSTS_COUNT = 10
```

В файле `views.py` используете:

```
from django.conf import settings

...
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()[:settings.POSTS_COUNT]
    ...
```

Comment: Какое имя пользователя, такое и поведение - копипаст с комментариев...